# Pandas: conditional merge/join data frames with duplicate ids

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Please excuse the title - I'm not really sure how best to describe my issue. I believe what I'm after might be something like a conditional outer join/merge. I'm thinking either the condition is set at the beginning, or everything is merged and the non-essential information is removed afterwards. I do have an example which hopefully will help explain my situation.

I am starting with the below data frames:

**Data Frame 1**

```
+--------+------------+
| GlobID | Issue      |
+--------+------------+
| 1      | Building M |
+--------+------------+
| 2      | Building V |
+--------+------------+
| 3      | Building H |
+--------+------------+
```

**Data Frame 2**

```
+----+---------+---------+------------+---------+---------+------------+
| ID | Issue_A | Note_A  | Location_A | Issue_B | Note_B  | Location_B |
+----+---------+---------+------------+---------+---------+------------+
| 1  | Y       | broken  | bathroom   | N       |         |            |
+----+---------+---------+------------+---------+---------+------------+
| 2  | Y       | stained | bedroom    | Y       | rusty   | basement   |
+----+---------+---------+------------+---------+---------+------------+
| 3  | Y       | missing | kitchen    | Y       | cracked | attic      |
+----+---------+---------+------------+---------+---------+------------+
```

- In data frame 2, the value of 'Note_A' and 'Location_A' is dependent on 'Issue_A' if there's an issue, then these will be populated. If not, 'Issue_A' is marked 'N' and the other columns remain empty. Basically, what I want is to consolidate the data such that for each ID, the issues are broken out into their own rows. Ideally, the result would not include records where no issue was recorded:

**Desired result:**

```
+--------+------------+---------+----------+
| GlobID | Name       | Issue   | Location |
+--------+------------+---------+----------+
| 1      | Building M | broken  | bathroom |
+--------+------------+---------+----------+
| 2      | Building V | stained | bedroom  |
+--------+------------+---------+----------+
| 2      | Building V | rusty   | basement |
+--------+------------+---------+----------+
| 3      | Building H | missing | kitchen  |
+--------+------------+---------+----------+
| 3      | Building H | cracked | attic    |
+--------+------------+---------+----------+
```

As I mentioned, I'm not sure whether an outer join is what I want here in conjunction with ffill to fill out the ids? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention, this is my current code:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2.set_index('ID'), left_on='GlobID', right_index=True)
```

This really only gets me df1 joined to df2. I still need to break out the issues so that they each take up their own row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple solution to your problem:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, "Building M"], [2, "Building V"], [3, "Building H"]], columns=["id", "Issue"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, "Y", "broken", "bathroom", "N", np.nan, np.nan], [2,"Y", "stained", "bedroom", "Y", "rusty", "basement"], [3, "Y", "missing", "kitchen", "Y", "cracked", "attic"]], columns=["id", "Issue_A", "Note_A", "Location_A", "Issue_B", "Note_B", "Location_B"])

df2 = pd.concat([df2[["id", "Issue_A", "Location_A"]], df2[["id", "Issue_B", "Location_B"]].rename(columns={"Issue_B" : "Issue_A", "Location_B" : "Location_A" })]).dropna()

df_result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="left")

print(df_result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped get me in the right direction! I may need to use 'melt' as well since I need to get the description of a building code joined to the final data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You may use such algorithm:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,"Building M"],[2,"Building V"], [3, "Building H"]], columns=["GlobID","Issue"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,"Y","broken","bathroom","N","",""],
                    [2,"Y","stained","bedroom","Y","rusty","basement"],
                    [3,"Y","missing","kitchen","Y","cracked","attic"]], 
                   columns=["ID","Issue_A","Note_A", "Location_A", "Issue_B", "Note_B", "Location_B"])

df1 = df1.set_index("GlobID")
df2 = df2.set_index("ID")

# divide our df2 to list of data frames
issues = ["A", "B"]
description = ["Issue", "Note", "Location"]
delimiter = "_"
issues_df_list = []
for issue in issues:
    # prepare concrete issue description fields
    issue_labels = [descr + delimiter + issue for descr in description]
    # select sub df for each issue
    df = df2[issue_labels]
    # rename and unify columns labels
    df.columns = description
    # then add sub df to the df list
    issues_df_list.append(df)

# then concat list of dfs to one big df
issues_df = pd.concat(issues_df_list,sort=False) # some kind of reshaping

# drop rows with "N" values
issues_df = issues_df[issues_df["Issue"] != "N"]

# drop Issue column
issues_df = issues_df.loc[:,issues_df.columns != "Issue"]

# rename Note column label to the Issue 
issues_df = issues_df.rename(columns={"Note":"Issue"})

issues_df
```

It gives you:

```
+----+---------+----------+
|    |  Issue  | Location |
+----+---------+----------+
| ID |         |          |
| 1  | broken  | bathroom |
| 2  | stained | bedroom  |
| 3  | missing | kitchen  |
| 2  | rusty   | basement |
| 3  | cracked | attic    |
+----+---------+----------+
```

And then you could make a simple merge:

```
pd.merge(df1.rename(columns={"Issue":"Name"}), issues_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)

+---+------------+---------+----------+
|   |    Name    |  Issue  | Location |
+---+------------+---------+----------+
| 1 | Building M | broken  | bathroom |
| 2 | Building V | stained | bedroom  |
| 2 | Building V | rusty   | basement |
| 3 | Building H | missing | kitchen  |
| 3 | Building H | cracked | attic    |
+---+------------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured there was more than 1 way to approach this!